# Add Gradient to Label of BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, gradient, navigationbar

In my flutter app I have a bottom navigation bar.
I want to add a LinearGradient to the selected item.

I managed to add a Gradient to the Icon by using the `activeIcon` attribute of BottomNavigationBarItem.

However I don't know how to add the same gradient to the label of the item.
Since `BottomNavigationBarItem.title` is deprecated and `BottomNavigationBarItem.label` only allows me to add a String I can not add the Gradient to the label directly.

I have tried messing with the `selectedLabelStyle` of the BottomNavigationBar but had no success.

Here is a screenshot of how my BottomNavigationBar looks.
[image: BottomNavigationBar]
Currently the Label has a single color. I want it to have the same gradient as the icon.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much!

```
       BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          currentIndex: _currentPage,
          backgroundColor: context.appTheme.primaryBackgroundColor,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          unselectedItemColor: context.appTheme.primaryTextColor,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: GradientMask(
                child: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                gradient: context.appTheme.primaryGradient,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: GradientMask(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                gradient: context.appTheme.primaryGradient,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: GradientMask(
                child: Icon(Icons.savings),
                gradient: context.appTheme.primaryGradient,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.savings),
              label: 'Earnings'
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: GradientMask(
                child: Icon(Icons.volunteer_activism),
                gradient: context.appTheme.primaryGradient,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.volunteer_activism),
              label: 'Sharing'
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              activeIcon: GradientMask(
                child: Icon(Icons.inventory_2),
                gradient: context.appTheme.primaryGradient,
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.inventory_2),
              label: 'My Items'
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon and active icon can also take a column widget. You can wrap the icon with a column and addthe relevant text in it and ignore the label.